# onComplete faster than map in Scala future

Tags: scala, akka, future

I have an `actor` case where I get all listeners from a list and send some responses (as json) to each of them.

```scala
    def process(subscribers: Set[ActorRef]): Receive = {
       case Push(request) => 
          DashboardsService.getWidgets(List(1, 3, 7, 12, 19)) map { widgets =>
         widgets.filter(x => !NotifierService.widgetsInUpdate.contains(x.id))
            .par
            .foreach(widget => {
                // add widget id to widgetsInUpdate
                NotifierService.widgetsInUpdate += widget.id

                // case 1: using onComplete
                val future = WidgetsService.getDataById(widget.id)
                future.onComplete {
                   case Success(json) => {
                      (subscribers - sender) ? json
                      NotifierService.widgetsInUpdate = NotifierService.widgetsInUpdate
                          .filter(_ != widget.id)
                   }
                   case Failure(_) => NotifierService.widgetsInUpdate = 
                      NotifierService.widgetsInUpdate
                          .filter(_ != widget.id)
                }

                // case 2: using map
                WidgetsService.getDataById(widget.id) map { json =>
                   (subscribers - sender) ? json
                   NotifierService.widgetsInUpdate = NotifierService.widgetsInUpdate
                      .filter(_ != widget.id)
                }
            })
         }
     }
    
    object NotifierService {
       var widgetsInUpdate: ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer.empty
    }
```

Because some queries run for a long time (7 8 seconds) and the actor is hit at each 3 or 4 seconds, I need to use a queue for widgets (widgetsInUpdate): If a widgets already exists in queue for a new request, then the widget will be skipped from executing another query, because already one is in pending for it.

So, is important that after `actorRef` asking for json data, to remove `widgetId` from the queue. First, I used `map` on future, but something happened and in time, some widgetIds freezes in the queue. A full request took around 10 seconds, but when I changed to use `onComplete`, I see it is done in maximum 3 or 4 seconds. How it is possible? Why `onComplete` seems to be faster than `map` operator? Because, in both cases I need to wait for response. Thanks

Comment: there are so many things wrong with your code. you're mutating some state outside of actor context `NotifierService.widgetsInUpdate += widget.id` is an example of this. I suggest to not mix actors with futures in they way you do. If you are forced to use a future don't do any `map` or `onComplete`. Do only `pipeTo`. Your whole code needs to be redesigned as result.

Comment: Thanks both for answers. Unfortunatelly, return type of the services and repositories is Future[T] as example Future[Entity] or Future[List[Entity]]. subscribers list contains all frontend clients which are connected with the backend; because some other 3rd party apps send a request to announce that some source tables are updated, my own server will connecting to his actor system and will push a notification, where response is builded and send to all subscribers;

Comment: Each subscriber receive a different response based on his request (requests are saved in a `Map`, where `actorName` is key and a json received from frontend is the value); the app is about some dashboards, and if the `client1` have `dashboardA` opened in browser, he will receive data for `dashboardA`, while `client2` which have `dashboardB` in browser will receive a different answer (this can be multiplied X times - if the application have around 100 dashboards)

Comment: Please use [pipeTo pattern](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.32/futures.html#use-the-pipe-pattern) instead of map/onComplete in your actors. This will force you to write less buggy code

Answer (score 2):

Ivan is correct that your usage of `Future`s within actors is buggy and throws away many of the useful guarantees of the actor model.

`onComplete` is faster than `map`/`flatMap` because `map` is implemented in terms of an `onComplete` which completes a `Promise` and may schedule a transformation.

Comment: I'll note also that an ask where you're throwing away the response is a pretty bad code smell.